# rails autosave associations raise exceptions with save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Thanks to rails `autosave` feature i know that associations are automatically saved.

Sometimes i have situations where certain associated models are not saved but the parent is, even though i am doing it inside a transaction.

```
class Conversation
  has_many :participations
  has_many :messages
end

class Participation
  belongs_to :conversation
end

class Message
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :participation
end


conversation = Conversation.new
sender = conversation.participations.build(foo)
receiver = conversation.participations.build(bar)
message = conversation.messages.build(sender: sender)


Conversation.transaction do 
  conversation.save!
end
```

Am I doing something wrong with this transaction/autosave? if i add validation to the message, can't I be certain that the parent will not save as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
class Conversation
  has_many :participations
  has_many :messages

  validates_associated :participations, :messages
end
```

This should also validate the nested relations. If there's a validation error in any child, the parent validation will also fail.

You can check the documentation about this method [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html).